# "Have" taking "ing" form

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, idiomatic-language, grammaticality-in-context

**They rose to the fame in the first act, and now they are having a spectacular fall at the will of the scribe**

As far as I know, "have" can't take "ing" form like we can't say "I am having a car",  then why the writer used " having" here? Can I use "getting" here instead of "having"?

Comment: Are you saying that 'having' is not a word?

Comment: @Michael_Harvey, Why is it wrong to say " I am having two sisters "?

Comment: 'I am having' is present continuous which is used about events which are in progress at the moment of speaking, or temporary states which are true around the moment of speaking. To talk about having two sisters, which is always true, we use the simple -present - 'I have two sisters'.  You could say I am having a baby, or I am having my mother to stay. Misuse of present continuous is very common in Indian English.

Comment: @Michael Harvey,  Could you explain what the writer meant by " having a spectacular fall"?

Comment: Do you know what 'spectacular' and 'fall' mean?

Comment: @Michael Harvey, Yap I know. I need to make sure in what sense the writer used "having". Is it "possession" or "experience"?

Comment: If you can imagine possessing a fall, please explain that to me, as I would be very interested.